# Atom installation dependancy error in kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, atom-editor

i was trying to install atom on kali linux and i got dependency error

```
sudo dpkg -i '/root/Downloads/atom-amd64(2).deb'
```

error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package atom.
(Reading database ... 407923 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Downloads/atom-amd64(2).deb ...
Unpacking atom (1.45.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5) | libgconf2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.
 atom depends on gvfs-bin; however:
  Package gvfs-bin is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for kali-menu (2020.2.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom
```

First i removed broken package with `sudo apt-get -f install`. Then tried to install libgconf-2-4 `sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4` and `sudo apt-get install -y gvfs-bin`. but both gave errors.

How to solve it??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: First i removed broken package with  sudo apt-get -f install. Then tried to install libgconf-2-4 sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4  and sudo apt-get install -y gvfs-bin. but both gave errors.

Comment: Use the edit button and add this and any other requested information to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` to make sure that it has the default repositories. The default repositories in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for Kali Linux rolling releases are:

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

You can edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file manually.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Kali can avoid a lot of problems if you don't populate the system's sources.list file with unofficial repositories. Because Atom text editor is a snap package, it is packaged as a standalone application and can be installed without breaking anything else with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update   
sudo apt install snapd   
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd apparmor  
sudo reboot  
sudo snap install atom --classic
```

Snap packages are updated automatically in the background when updates become available.

Comment: my /etc/apt/sources.list was empty.. now it got installed.. thanks mate